# Creator Update and Windows Update

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update

I have about 30 Windows 10 Professional computers. Some domain some standalone. All had problems with the Creator Update.

The first issue is when you go in to Windows Update I see a red warning at the top "*Some settings are hidden or managed by your organization". That is incorrect. I have checked the GPO on several and nothing under Windows Update is set.

From there if you click on "Advanced options" there is the same red warning at the top and "Give me updates for other Microsoft products when I update Windows" is un-checked and grayed-out.

I have tried the registry change (HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate) and the GPEdit change and neither work. The internet is flooded with this problem. Most say it happened at the Anniversary update but some of my workstations are fresh Creator installs. No one seems to have a fix.

I have gotten rid of the warning and was able to check the "Give me updates for other..." but am not sure how. A combination of something. One way or the other whenever I do a Windows Update and it installs the Cumulative 1703 it reverts back. Has anyone found a permanent fix?

Comment: Do you have any GPO of WSUS. Whether You have Local WSUS Server. Some settings are hidden or managed by your organization usual comes if that is not bind with Microsoft Account.

Comment: As mentioned some of these are fresh installs but if you want me to look at some specific GPO setting please tell me what you want me to check.

Comment: Some settings are hidden or managed by your organization. 
This is based on that in the privacy settings under "Settings" -> "Privacy" -> "Feedback & diagnostics" -> "Diagnostics and usage data" it is set to "Basic". Change it to "Enhanced/Full" or higher, the message disappears.

Can You Go to Run `rsop.msc`  You get all the group Policy. Right Click on Computer Configuration/User Configuration Check any policy related to WSUS Server.

Comment: The two options under "Feedback and Diagnostics" are "Basic" and "Full". Setting it to Full didn't change anything. RSOP yielded nothing (as did gpresult). @Ramhound what do you mean "Unless you provide specifics about which settings you are talking about I cannot submit an answer to this question"? That is a little nebulous. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are looking for but here is Computer Configuration=>Windows Components=>Windows Update from a standalone. Nothing is configured on the standalones or the domains. But you are going to love this. Not the warning is gone and the option to "get other updates" is checkable. In another four hours it will reverse..... OK I give. How do you upload a screenshot?